# How to parse a complex Json value in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON which is a combination of simple and complicated structures.Anyhow you can have a look at it.All I want is to get the "playlist_url": value and display it a listview builder.Along with that I want to parse for 2 text values which I am able to do.But the url part is where I am not able to resolve

The JSON structure(it is too long,thats y I have given the link): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1saJN3MQvG55M1ipf42-65Etowi_kW80gkrosU6vBb5o/edit?usp=sharing

The PODO file:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final homePage = homePageFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

HomePage homePageFromJson(String str) => HomePage.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String homePageToJson(HomePage data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class HomePage {
  HomePage({
    this.series,
    this.homeBanners,
    this.liveChannels,
    this.publishers,
    this.musicCategories,
    this.musicPlaylists,
    this.movies,
  });

  List<HomeBanner> series;
  List<HomeBanner> homeBanners;
  List<LiveChannel> liveChannels;
  List<Publisher> publishers;
  List<Music> musicCategories;
  Music musicPlaylists;
  List<HomeBanner> movies;

  factory HomePage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HomePage(
        series: List<HomeBanner>.from(
            json["series"].map((x) => HomeBanner.fromJson(x))),
        homeBanners: List<HomeBanner>.from(
            json["home_banners"].map((x) => HomeBanner.fromJson(x))),
        liveChannels: List<LiveChannel>.from(
            json["live_channels"].map((x) => LiveChannel.fromJson(x))),
        publishers: List<Publisher>.from(
            json["publishers"].map((x) => Publisher.fromJson(x))),
        musicCategories: List<Music>.from(
            json["music_categories"].map((x) => Music.fromJson(x))),
        musicPlaylists: Music.fromJson(json["music_playlists"]),
        movies: List<HomeBanner>.from(
            json["movies"].map((x) => HomeBanner.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "series": List<dynamic>.from(series.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "home_banners": List<dynamic>.from(homeBanners.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "live_channels":
            List<dynamic>.from(liveChannels.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "publishers": List<dynamic>.from(publishers.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "music_categories":
            List<dynamic>.from(musicCategories.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "music_playlists": musicPlaylists.toJson(),
        "movies": List<dynamic>.from(movies.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class HomeBanner {
  HomeBanner({
    this.movieId,
    this.title,
    this.tags,
    this.genres,
    this.thumbnail,
    this.posterLink,
    this.platform,
    this.worldwide,
    this.createdAt,
    this.seriesId,
  });

  String movieId;
  String title;
  List<String> tags;
  List<String> genres;
  List<String> thumbnail;
  String posterLink;
  Platform platform;
  double worldwide;
  DateTime createdAt;
  String seriesId;

  factory HomeBanner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HomeBanner(
        movieId: json["movie_id"] == null ? null : json["movie_id"],
        title: json["title"],
        tags: List<String>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
        genres: List<String>.from(json["genres"].map((x) => x)),
        thumbnail: List<String>.from(json["thumbnail"].map((x) => x)),
        posterLink: json["poster_link"],
        platform: platformValues.map[json["platform"]],
        worldwide: json["WORLDWIDE"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
        seriesId: json["series_id"] == null ? null : json["series_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "movie_id": movieId == null ? null : movieId,
        "title": title,
        "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x)),
        "genres": List<dynamic>.from(genres.map((x) => x)),
        "thumbnail": List<dynamic>.from(thumbnail.map((x) => x)),
        "poster_link": posterLink,
        "platform": platformValues.reverse[platform],
        "WORLDWIDE": worldwide,
        "createdAt": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "series_id": seriesId == null ? null : seriesId,
      };
}

enum Platform { YOUTUBE, DISCOVERYPLUS }

final platformValues = EnumValues(
    {"discoveryplus": Platform.DISCOVERYPLUS, "youtube": Platform.YOUTUBE});

class LiveChannel {
  LiveChannel({
    this.keyId,
    this.postContent,
    this.publisherId,
    this.publisherName,
    this.publisherProfilePic,
    this.publisherDesc,
    this.downvotesCount,
    this.upvotesCount,
  });

  String keyId;
  PostContent postContent;
  String publisherId;
  String publisherName;
  String publisherProfilePic;
  String publisherDesc;
  int downvotesCount;
  int upvotesCount;

  factory LiveChannel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LiveChannel(
        keyId: json["key_id"],
        postContent: PostContent.fromJson(json["post_content"]),
        publisherId: json["publisher_id"],
        publisherName: json["publisher_name"],
        publisherProfilePic: json["publisher_profile_pic"],
        publisherDesc: json["publisher_desc"],
        downvotesCount: json["downvotes_count"],
        upvotesCount: json["upvotes_count"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "key_id": keyId,
        "post_content": postContent.toJson(),
        "publisher_id": publisherId,
        "publisher_name": publisherName,
        "publisher_profile_pic": publisherProfilePic,
        "publisher_desc": publisherDesc,
        "downvotes_count": downvotesCount,
        "upvotes_count": upvotesCount,
      };
}

class PostContent {
  PostContent({
    this.shortcode,
    this.platformVideoLink,
    this.caption,
    this.description,
  });

  String shortcode;
  String platformVideoLink;
  String caption;
  String description;

  factory PostContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostContent(
        shortcode: json["shortcode"],
        platformVideoLink: json["platform_videoLink"],
        caption: json["caption"],
        description: json["description"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "shortcode": shortcode,
        "platform_videoLink": platformVideoLink,
        "caption": caption,
        "description": description,
      };
}

class Music {
  Music({
    this.id,
    this.country,
    this.categoryId,
    this.categoryName,
    this.categoryIcons,
    this.playlists,
  });

  dynamic id;
  String country;
  String categoryId;
  String categoryName;
  List<CategoryIcon> categoryIcons;
  List<Playlist> playlists;

  factory Music.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Music(
        id: json["_id"],
        country: json["country"],
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
        categoryName: json["category_name"],
        categoryIcons: List<CategoryIcon>.from(
            json["category_icons"].map((x) => CategoryIcon.fromJson(x))),
        playlists: List<Playlist>.from(
            json["playlists"].map((x) => Playlist.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "country": country,
        "category_id": categoryId,
        "category_name": categoryName,
        "category_icons":
            List<dynamic>.from(categoryIcons.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "playlists": List<dynamic>.from(playlists.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class CategoryIcon {
  CategoryIcon({
    this.height,
    this.url,
    this.width,
  });

  int height;
  String url;
  int width;

  factory CategoryIcon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CategoryIcon(
        height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
        url: json["url"],
        width: json["width"] == null ? null : json["width"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "height": height == null ? null : height,
        "url": url,
        "width": width == null ? null : width,
      };
}

class Playlist {
  Playlist({
    this.playlistName,
    this.playlistDescription,
    this.playlistUrl,
    this.playlistTotalTracks,
    this.playlistImages,
    this.playlistFollowers,
    this.playlistId,
  });

  String playlistName;
  String playlistDescription;
  String playlistUrl;
  int playlistTotalTracks;
  List<CategoryIcon> playlistImages;
  int playlistFollowers;
  String playlistId;

  factory Playlist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Playlist(
        playlistName: json["playlist_name"],
        playlistDescription: json["playlist_description"],
        playlistUrl: json["playlist_url"],
        playlistTotalTracks: json["playlist_total_tracks"],
        playlistImages: List<CategoryIcon>.from(
            json["playlist_images"].map((x) => CategoryIcon.fromJson(x))),
        playlistFollowers: json["playlist_followers"],
        playlistId: json["playlist_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "playlist_name": playlistName,
        "playlist_description": playlistDescription,
        "playlist_url": playlistUrl,
        "playlist_total_tracks": playlistTotalTracks,
        "playlist_images":
            List<dynamic>.from(playlistImages.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "playlist_followers": playlistFollowers,
        "playlist_id": playlistId,
      };
}

class Publisher {
  Publisher({
    this.platform,
    this.username,
    this.fullName,
    this.profilePicUrl,
    this.content,
    this.keyId,
  });

  Platform platform;
  String username;
  String fullName;
  String profilePicUrl;
  Content content;
  String keyId;

  factory Publisher.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Publisher(
        platform: platformValues.map[json["platform"]],
        username: json["username"],
        fullName: json["full_name"],
        profilePicUrl: json["profile_pic_url"],
        content: Content.fromJson(json["content"]),
        keyId: json["key_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "platform": platformValues.reverse[platform],
        "username": username,
        "full_name": fullName,
        "profile_pic_url": profilePicUrl,
        "content": content.toJson(),
        "key_id": keyId,
      };
}

class Content {
  Content({
    this.description,
  });

  String description;

  factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
        description: json["description"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "description": description,
      };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

The class called services where I am trying to parse the playlist_url.I am able to parse the playlist name and the number of videos of it(the count of it)

```
class Services {
  static const String url =
      "https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v2/home?pageLocation=home&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
      "user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";

  static Future<List<String>> loadDataForPlaylistDetailsForButtomTitle() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there");
      final homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);
      Playlist playListObject = new Playlist();
      List<String> lst_names = [];
      for (playListObject in homePage.musicPlaylists.playlists)
        lst_names.add(playListObject.playlistName);

      print("Buttom titles");
      print(lst_names);
      return lst_names;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<List<String>> loadDataForPlaylistDetailsForCount() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there");
      final homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);
      Playlist playListObject = new Playlist();
      List<String> lst_names = [];
      for (playListObject in homePage.musicPlaylists.playlists)
        lst_names.add(playListObject.playlistTotalTracks.toString());
      print("count");
      print(lst_names);
      return lst_names;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<List<Playlist>> loadDataForPlaylistDetailsForImageUrl() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there");
      final homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);
      Music musicObject = new Music();

      List<Playlist> playlistObj = homePage.musicPlaylists.playlists;

      print("category icon object returned");

      return playlistObj;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the main file where I am trying to display in listView.First the data is loaded in initstate and then stored in arrays.But for the last one (the url stuff)I tried with the object it self as things became complicated

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
 Services.loadDataForPlaylistDetailsForButtomTitle().then((playListNames) {
      setState(() {
        _playListNames = playListNames ;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForPlaylistDetailsForButtomTitle().then((playListCount) {
      setState(() {
        _playListtotalTracks = playListCount ;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForPlaylistDetailsForImageUrl().then((objUrl) {
      setState(() {
        _obj = objUrl ;
      });
    });
  }
```

The code for listView Builder:

```
Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.41,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: _playListImageUrls.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.34,
                      child: PhysicalModel(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(35),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(35)),
                        child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.285,
                          image:  _obj[index].playlistImages[index].url,
                          placeholder: cupertinoActivityIndicator,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 0, 0),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                        child: Text(
                            _playListNames[index],
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                        child: Text(
                          _playListtotalTracks[index],
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Also I find myself repeating this structures many times.Any suggestions to improvise would be equally welcomed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63538614/9129854 this could help with reading the JSON file

Comment: Thanks I have figured out the solution finally

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the solution.The whole point where I was doing the mistake was assuming things as a list of object,rather it was a list of list of single object.

The following modifications were made:

In service file

```
 static Future<List<String>> loadDataForPlaylistDetailsForImageUrl() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is thereeeeeeeee");
      final homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);
      Playlist playListObject = new Playlist();
      List<String> urlList = [];
      List<dynamic> lst_names = [];
      for (playListObject in homePage.musicPlaylists.playlists) {
        lst_names.add(playListObject.playlistImages);
        print(lst_names);
      }

      //lst_names=
      print("objjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
      for (var listobj in lst_names) {
        for (var obj in listobj) {
          print(obj.url.toString());
          urlList.add(obj.url.toString());
        }
      }

      return urlList;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Also in main file:

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.285,
                          image: _musicPlaylistImgUrlList[index],
                          //_categoryIconfor[index].url,
                          //_obj[index].playlistImages[index].url,
                          placeholder: cupertinoActivityIndicator,
                          fit: BoxFit.none,
                        ),
```